# How to hibernate an android app and release the memory

Tags: java, android

I want to hibernate an android app say facebook. I want to store all the data from that app and remove this app from memory completely in such a way that when I start the app next time, it resumes from where it was closed. The app should not remain in the memory until I start it next time.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean save erase it as if to remove the application itself?
or remove it as if close it in the application manager?

Comment: I just want to close it from the memory. It will still remain in the installed apps. But until i start it next time it should not remain in RAM. and also when I start it it should show me the old content where it was closed.

Comment: basically close it in the application manager

Comment: well I know you can use ActivityLifecycleCallbacks but that will only work when the app is on the background I guess you can't do it once you cleared it from everyplace in the memory you can try and use a bypass though and keep a service seperated from every UI to run on the background then once the application class goes down try and save the bundle - it should contain all the relevant info for the UI on screen